# What should be expected and actual values when testing the "getCustomer" method in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, junit

I have two quesition for you. I added my test methods to code line. What should be the values of "expected" and "actual" for test method? And how can I test truely my custom exception in test method with try-catch or anything? Could you help?

`I define "customerList" on top`
private List customerList=new ArrayList<>();

``````````
`````````There is a "getCustomer" method in the "Bank" class`````````

public Customer getCustomer(int ID) throws CustomerNotFoundException {

        for (int i = 0; i < customerList.size(); i++) {
            if (customerList.get(i).getId() == ID) {
                return customerList.get(i);
            }
        }
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException(ID);
    }
```````

`````````There is a "addCustomer" method`````````

public void addCustomer(int id, String name){
        customerList.add(new Customer(name, id));
    }

`````````There is a "getCustomer" test that I ask`````````

/** Test getCustomer()**/
    @Test public void tc504_Bank(){
        try {
            Bank b = new Bank("Test Name", "Test Address");
            b.addCustomer(1, "Test Name");
            b.getCustomer(1);
            Assert.assertEquals("Customer Not Found", b.getCustomerList().get(0), ??? );
        }catch (CustomerNotFoundException e){
            Assert.assertEquals("PIN not all digits", 0, 1);
        }
    }
````````

`````````There is a custom expection class````````

public class CustomerNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public CustomerNotFoundException(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public CustomerNotFoundException(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CustomerNotFoundException(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerNotFoundException: id - " + id + " name - " + name;

    }
}
``````````

Answer (score 1):

Based on which version of junit library you are using:

**JUnit4**

```
 @Test(expected = CustomerNotFoundException.class) 
 public void tc504_Bank(){
        Bank b = new Bank("Test Name", "Test Address");
        b.addCustomer(1, "Test Name");
        b.getCustomer(1);
 }
```

**JUnit5**

```
 @Test public void tc504_Bank(){
        Bank b = new Bank("Test Name", "Test Address");
        b.addCustomer(1, "Test Name");
        assertThrows(CustomerNotFoundException.class, () -> {
            b.getCustomer(1);
        });  
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Thank you for your help. It worked.